# Extract value from wp-config.php with sed

Tags: sed

For some deployment scripts I want to extract the `DB_USER` value ('wordpress' in the example) of my `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('DB_USER', 'wordpress');
```

I think `sed` should be the best tool but I don't find the correct combination.

Comment: Why is `sed` your preferred option? If you have control of the contents of the PHP file (and can asure that it does not contail malicious content), why don't you run `php -r "include('wp-config.php'); echo DB_USER;"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion uses awk:

```
grep DB_USER wp-config | awk -F\' '{print $4}'
```

Comment: No need for `grep` + `awk`, just do `awk -F\' '/DB_USER/ {print $4}' wp-config.php`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n "/^ *define( *'DB_USER', *'\([^']*\)'.*/ {s//\1/p;q;}" wp-config.file
```

in case of absolute use of sed